# Send message en hook success - Delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

How can I send a message when the job finishes successfully? I would like to send the message and show it in a `swal` in javascript when the work finishes correctly, but I do not know how to do this, any suggestions?

I do not need to do anything other than send a message

```
class CompileProjectJob < Struct.new(:url)
  def perform
  end

  def success(job)
     #send message when the work is successful
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of `perform` method queue new delayed job for sending the message

```
class CompileProjectJob < Struct.new(:url)
  def perform
    # the code here of this job 
    # queue new job 
  end
end
```

the code of the perform method is executed sequentially as any regular code

**Update**

to send the message to the front end there are two ways (push and  pull) [more info](https://simplicable.com/new/pull-vs-push-technology)
 - push: using web sockets you push the message from the backend to the front end 
 - pull: the front end sends requests every certain period to check if the backend has a new data

and you can use any of these techniques to solve the problem

if you used **pulling** you will make the job update a data store as an example Redis or mysql. the front end will send a request every interval to check for the new data  in some scenarios this will be a better solution but i think you are looking for the other technique

**pushing**: 
here you can use something like active cable https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html
or a third party like pusher https://www.pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-table-ruby-rails
the main idea here your frontend app will open a websocket connection with your server. this socket will stay opened and listen for any updates from the backend through a channel so when you send the update after finishing the job through this channel it will be received by the front end so you can add code to show the message

Comment: my question is how can I send a message to a javascript alert in perform?

Comment: using web sockets .. one of the easiest solutions to use something like pusher https://www.pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-table-ruby-rails
then you will send the message to pusher server which has an opened WebSocket  with your web client application so the user will say real-time updates check the tutorial in the link

Comment: also, you can use action cable for that https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html it works in a similar way to pusher

Comment: Thanks for your help, it has helped me a lot!